# Client side validation on normal (not submit) button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Here is my code, simplified:

```
<form id="form1" style="height: 759px" runat="server">
    <%= Html.TextBox("txtDateFrom")%>
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd" onclick="return btnAdd_onclick()" />
</form>
```

I want to add a validator on client side. For example, it will control the entered text's in the textBox length.

Important: I don't have a model passed in that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to use Jquery use JQuery Validation Plugins

eg.[Jquery Validation Plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)
and [Position Absolute Jquery validation plugin](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use jquery validation add-in?